# Аналог "from module import something" в delphi

Tags: delphi

В [python](/questions/tagged/python) я например пишу

```
from random import randint
```

Есть ли аналог этого в [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi)?

Answer (score 5):

Есть, конечно. Отдельные модули представлены в виде DLL или иных PE-файлов.
Возможны два основных способа подгрузки - статический и динамический.

Статический:

```
interface
...
function Nya(Arg1: Integer): Integer; stdcall; // соглашение вызова может быть и иным 
...
implementation
...
function Nya; external 'Nya.dll';
```

После чего функцию Nya можно использовать везде, где данный .pas файл есть в секции uses.
Функция запишется в секцию импорта exe и при отсутствии библиотеки программа просто не запустится.

Динамический:

Необходимо объявить тип для функции - чтобы компилятор знал, какие аргументы она принимает и что возвращает. После чего подгрузить перед использованием библиотеку, найти функцию в ней, получить её адрес и использовать:

```
type
...
TNya = function(Arg1: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
...
implementation
...
function TestNya()
var
 hDLL: THandle;
 Nya: TNya;

begin
   // Попытка загрузки библиотеки
   hDLL := LoadLibrary('Nya.dll');
   // Если библиотека загрузилась
   if (hDLL <> 0) then
      // Попытка найти функцию в библиотеке и получить адрес
      @Nya := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'Nya');
      // Функция имеется
      if(@Nya <> Nil)
         // Использование
         ShowMessage(IntToStr(Nya(123));
      end;
      // Выгрузка библиотеки - она больше не нужна
      FreeLibrary(hDLL);
   end;
end;
```

Таким образом можно сделать систему плагинов, например. Когда названия библиотек заранее неизвестны.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаком с питоном, но если речь идет об иницализации генератора случайных чисел,
то это

Randomize

Ну, а потом для генерации

Random()

Comment: Это был просто пример. Я вообще говорю об импорте отдельных функций из модулей.

Comment: Затрудняюсь понять, о чем речь. Для использования отдельных модулей просто нужно вписать их в блок uses и все функции (а также и все остальное) будут доступны.
Может если сможете подробно описать задачу, что надо сделать, cмогу сказать, как это реализовать в delphi.

Comment: я имел ввиду импорт одной функции из модуля, а не его всего.  
лано, уже не надо.